# Convert JMSMessage to SOAP message in MULE ESB

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, esb, mule-studio

e have already produced the webservices at `"http://localhost:5050/MyServices"`.Tried with proxying of webservices with HTTP endpoints, it is working fine.

But now we are trying to use the JMS in the middile of these HTTP end points. my services are getting the request, but unable to understand JMS message. Is there any way to convert JMSMessage to SOAP message.

flow is : SOAP UI ==> JMS (MULE ESB) ==> MyServices at 5050

!Flow im mule][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x8es.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

A JMS message from SoapUI is just a String containing the SOAP request XML when it arrives in the Mule JMS inbound endpoint, so you should be able to just send it to a http endpoint with required headers.

For example like this:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="JMS_Connector" doc:description="Generated by ArchStudio" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="test.queue"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="wsf.cdyne.com" port="80" path="WeatherWS/Weather.asmx" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
       <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
</http:outbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: What problem do you get when you follow Anton's suggestion? Please post the error.

Comment: To which address, i need to send request (from SOAP UI).

Comment: You need to configure the JMS endpoint in HermesJMS and then setup SoapUI to use that endpoint. You can also test directly with HermesJMS. http://www.soapui.org/JMS/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can also use :-

```
<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
```

after `jms:inbound-endpoint` and before `http:outbound-endpoint`